# PuTTy does not use Pageant for authentication

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, putty

Aim is to use Pageant with PuTTy to avoid giving the key phrase multiple times a day. With default configuration in PuTTy, specifying `username@host` is not enough to trigger it to use the Pageant that is running on the background with the key loaded.

What kind of configuration options I would possibly looking for to change?

Comment: (As well as being posted on the wrong site, this is incredibly vague - please edit it to give more details.)

Comment: This should probably be at superuser.

Answer (score 1):

Under the settings view (left-hand side), expand "Connection" then "SSH" then "Auth" and checkoff "Attempt authentication using Pageant".

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the wrong username for the site then PuTTY will say "No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)" even though Pageant is running perfectly well and PuTTY is connecting to it.

So make sure you get the username right as well!